# Can I use loops inside a Rust Mustache MapBuilder?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to use loops inside a Rust Mustache (https://github.com/erickt/rust-mustache) MapBuilder to populate the contents of the vector? I've attached a semi-working example, it works with the struct version but not with the builder version.

**Edit:** The code compiles now thanks to Paul. I was missing two things: `|mut builder|` and `builder = builder.push_map`.

The thing is I do not want to use the struct version as I'll need to iterate over the images vector and mutate an item based on an certain condition (and I don't want to change the original vector).

I've looked here https://github.com/erickt/rust-mustache/blob/master/src/builder.rs but none of these code snippets show a loop example. Either it is not possible or I'm doing something wrong. I also created an issue but the erickt doesn't seem very active there.

Thank you.

`main.rs`:

```
extern crate serialize;

// [dependencies.rust-mustache]
//
// # git = "https://github.com/erickt/rust-mustache.git"
// git = "https://github.com/tsurai/rust-mustache.git"
extern crate mustache;

mod with_struct;
mod with_builder;

fn main() {
    with_struct::go();
    with_builder::go();
}
```

`with_builder.rs`:

```
use std::io;

use mustache;
use mustache::MapBuilder;

struct Image {
    name: String,
    file: String
}

impl Image {
    fn new(name: &str, file: &str) -> Image {
        Image {
            name: String::from_str(name),
            file: String::from_str(file)
        }
    }
}

pub fn go() {
    let images   = load_images();
    let template = mustache::compile_str(template());

    let data = MapBuilder::new()
        .insert_vec("images", |mut builder| {
        //                      ^~~~~ Need mutableb builder
            for image in images.iter() {
                builder = builder.push_map(|builder| {
                // ^~~~~~~~~~^~~~~ Need to re-assign the builder
                    builder
                        .insert_str("name", image.name.clone())
                        .insert_str("file", image.file.clone())
                });
            }
            builder
            // ^~~~~ Can now return it
        })
        .build();

    let _ = template.render_data(&mut io::stdout(), &data);
}

fn template<'a>() -> &'a str {
    "
        <ul>
        {{#images}}
            <li>
                <a href=\"{{file}}\">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
        {{/images}}
        </ul>
    "
}

fn load_images() -> Vec<Image> {
    let mut images = Vec::new();

    images.push(Image::new("Picture 1", "picture-1.png"));
    images.push(Image::new("Picture 2", "picture-2.png"));
    images.push(Image::new("Picture 3", "picture-3.png"));

    images
}
```

`with_struct.rs`:

```
use std::io;

use mustache;

#[deriving(Encodable)]
struct Image {
    name: String,
    file: String
}

#[deriving(Encodable)]
struct TemplateData<'a> {
    images: &'a Vec<Image>
}

impl Image {
    fn new(name: &str, file: &str) -> Image {
        Image {
            name: String::from_str(name),
            file: String::from_str(file)
        }
    }
}

pub fn go() {
    let images   = load_images();
    let template = mustache::compile_str(template());

    let data = TemplateData {
        images: &images
    };

    let _ = template.render(&mut io::stdout(), &data);
}

fn template<'a>() -> &'a str {
    "
        <ul>
        {{#images}}
            <li>
                <a href=\"{{file}}\">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
        {{/images}}
        </ul>
    "
}

fn load_images() -> Vec<Image> {
    let mut images = Vec::new();

    images.push(Image::new("Picture 1", "picture-1.png"));
    images.push(Image::new("Picture 2", "picture-2.png"));
    images.push(Image::new("Picture 3", "picture-3.png"));

    images
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ollie!

You need to remove the semicolon after last insert_str (Rust discards that line, and don't use as return value, if you put semicolon in the end).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think I was there too, the problem is that the builder becomes moved in the loop. I tried hacking around with `let mut b = &mut builder;` but that didn't work and builder isn't clonable.

Comment: Then, you just need mutable variable for builder, and do "builder = builder.push_map(..)"

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the problem as I can't do this ".insert_vec("images", |builder| { let mut b = &mut builder.clone(); ... }".

Comment: You don't need clone. Just `|mut builder| { for image in images.iter() { builder = builder.push_map(...); } return builder }` or `|bld| { let mut builder = bld; for image in images.iter() { builder = builder.push_map(...); } return builder }`

Comment: Ah, I tried that too but was missing the builder = builder reassignment. Thanks, it works now. :-) Funny how brain can forget the basic when encountering the complicated.